# Matching types .Net Core with ReactJS (typeScript)

Tags: arrays, .net, reactjs

I am trying to match a data structure from .NET Core : byte[] with a data structure from ReactJS (typeScript) for printing an image. Do you know what data type could I use in React to match this byte array from .NET? 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think a string data structure would be perfect for mapping  with the byte array from .net core.

Regards

Comment: Thank you! A lot! It works. I think it mapped to a string by default the byte array.

Comment: Could you also explain why you think this is a good approach, this might help others figuring these kind of questions ouit by themselves

Comment: In the absence of a perfectly mapping data structure, string seems to be the most suitable one for converting the byte array.